# how to extract files from ISO on linux?

Tags: linux, iso-image

I have an ISO file on a Linux machine for which I don't have root access. I am looking for some command or software that would allow me to extract all the files on the ISO without the need for root. Any ideas?

Comment: mount says it requires root access, btw.

Comment: It looks like the 7-zip answer someone else posted was deleted because you mentioned it was Windows-only, but I was going to point out that there is a Linux command-line version of 7-zip.

Comment: I think the 7-zip answer should be added back and toggled as a good answer, that's what I decided to use eventually (on Linux), and it works perfectly fine. Thanks to whoever gave me the hint about it.

Comment: The relevant package will probably be called p7zip (for Posix 7-ZIP). Also, does file-roller support ISO?

Comment: I copied my Linux 7zip comment into my answer, but if the other person undeletes the original 7zip answer, feel free to accept that one.

Comment: If you have read access for that iso, you could copy it to an usb stick, boot a live cd on another pc and mount the iso there.

Answer (score 2):

7-zip will do what you want.  There is a Linux command-line version of 7-zip.

Midnight Commander (`mc` from the shell prompt) can read ISO files and extract files/directories. It used to be installed by default in some distros; I'm not sure if it still is.

You could also try [xorriso](http://www.gnu.org/software/xorriso/) in reverse mode:

> one may enable reverse operation of xorriso and copy files or trees to
>   disk:
>
> ```
> $ xorriso -acl on -xattr on \
>    -indev /dev/sr0 \
>    -osirrox on \
>    -cpx '/pictures/private/horses*/*buttercup*' \
>        /home/her/buttercup_dir -- \
>    -extract /sounds /home/her/sounds_from_me
> ```
>
> Each copy command processes its files sorted by block address in the ISO image in order to reduce head moves with optical media. This
>   can bring effective read performance near to the raw media reading
>   speed.
>   Consider to enter dialog mode and use commands like -cd , -du , -lsl , -find.

Comment: mc is not installed in ubunut :'(

Comment: bummer...any luck with xorisso or 7zip?

Comment: as I said, 7zip works perfectly fine on Linux.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your other comment before; I guess we posted around the same time.

Comment: Provided you don't have the `7za` executable (CentOS); ISOs are not supported in `7za`. You can check supported formats with `7za i`.

Answer (score 1):

Midnight Commander (mc) seems the best option but it needs the mkisofs (or genisoimage) package to be able to open the image file (with the isoinfo utility).

With mc I've been able to copy the content of an image file without using mount or similar. In my platform 7-zip wasn't available.

Answer (score 0):

[AcetoneISO](http://www.acetoneteam.org/) can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Short & Sweet! try, 
- http://www.littlesvr.ca/isomaster/ 
- http://linuxappfinder.com/package/isomaster 
- http://pkgs.org/download/isomaster

Screenshot,
- http://www.littlesvr.ca/isomaster/sshots/

Answer (score 0):

first you mount the iso then extract the files from it

```
# mount -t iso9660 -o loop isoname /dirname
```

Comment: This requires root privileges, which the OP does not have on the host in question.